# Replacing scan by gsub in Ruby: how to allow code in gsub block?

Tags: ruby, regex, wiki

I am parsing a Wiki text from an XML dump, for a string named 'section' which includes templates in double braces, including some arguments, which I want to reorganize.

This has an example named TextTerm:

```
section="Sample of a text with a first template {{TextTerm|arg1a|arg2a|arg3a...}}  and then a second {{TextTerm|arg1b|arg2b|arg3b...}} etc."
```

I can use `scan` and a regex to get each template and work on it on a loop using:

```
section.scan(/\{\{(TextTerm)\|(.*?)\|(.*?)\}\}/i).each { |item| puts "1=" + item[1] # arg1a etc.}
```

And, I have been able to extract the database of the first argument of the template.

Now I also want to replace the name of the template "NewTextTerm" and reorganize its arguments by placing the second argument in place of the first.

Can I do it in the same loop? For example by changing `scan` by a `gsub(rgexp){ block}`:

```
section.gsub!(/\{\{(TextTerm)\|(.*?)\|(.*?)\}\}/) { |item| '{{NewTextTerm|\2|\1}}'}
```

I get:

```
"Sample of a text with a first template {{NewTextTerm|\\2|\\1}}  and then a second {{NewTextTerm|\\2|\\1}} etc."
```

meaning that the arguments of the regexp are not recognized. Even if it worked, I would like to have some place within the `gsub` block to work on the arguments. For example, I can't have a `puts` in the `gsub` block similar to the `scan().each` block but only a string to be substituted.

Any ideas are welcome.

PS: Some editing: braces and "section= added", code is complete.

Comment: This comment deserves to be an answer so it can be properly upvoted.

Comment: Do you mean double **brackets** or double **braces**?

Comment: Show a full example of your code, not single lines. There might be better ways to handle the entire problem in a short loop, but without seeing your code we don't know what you've set up. As a result, we can suggest incremental improvements, but we might be able to suggest something radically better. We also need to see a large sample of the text you're working with: Are there repeating `{{...}}` blocks, with the same set of tags throughout the file? Writing a template processing engine isn't hard but we need better information.

Answer (score 0):

When you have the replacement as a string argument, you can use `'\1'`, etc. like this:

```
string.gsub!(regex, '...\1...\2...')
```

When you have the replacement as a block, you can use `"#$1"`, etc. like this:

```
string.gsub!(regex){"...#$1...#$2..."}
```

You are mixing the uses. Stick to either one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, changing the quote by a double quote isn't enough, #$1 is the answer. Here is the complete code:

```
section="Sample of a text with a first template {{TextTerm|arg1a|arg2a|arg3a...}}  and then a second {{TextTerm|arg1b|arg2b|arg3b...}} etc."
section.gsub(/\{\{(TextTerm)\|(.*?)\|(.*?)\}\}/) { |item| "{{New#$1|#$3|#$2}}"}
"Sample of a text with a first template {{NewTextTerm|arg2a|arg3a...|arg1a}}  and then a second {{NewTextTerm|arg2b|arg3b...|arg1b}} etc."
```

Thus, it works. Thanks.

But now I have  to replace the string, by a "function" returning the changed string:

```
def stringreturn(arg1,arg2,arg3) strr = "{{New"+arg1 + arg3 +arg2 + "}}"; return strr ; end
```

and

```
section.gsub(/\{\{(TextTerm)\|(.*?)\|(.*?)\}\}/) { |item| stringreturn("#$1","|#$2","|#$3") }
```

will return:

```
"Sample of a text with a first template {{NewTextTerm|arg2a|arg3a...|arg1a}}  and then a second {{NewTextTerm|arg2b|arg3b...|arg1b}} etc."
```

Thanks to all!
There is probably a better way to manipulate arguments in MediaWiki templates using Ruby.